# How to create function for array

Tags: php, laravel

I need a function to find pairs of numbers that add up to a given target sum in an array of arrays. Here's an example array:

```
array:10 [
  0 => array:2 [
    0 => 6
    1 => 3
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    0 => 7
    1 => 5
  ]
  2 => array:2 [
    0 => 9
    1 => 5
  ]
  3 => array:2 [
    0 => 12
    1 => 4
  ]
  4 => array:2 [
    0 => 61
    1 => 1
  ]
  5 => array:2 [
    0 => 62
    1 => 1
  ]
  6 => array:2 [
    0 => 63
    1 => 1
  ]
  7 => array:2 [
    0 => 84
    1 => 5
  ]
  8 => array:2 [
    0 => 85
    1 => 4
  ]
  9 => array:2 [
    0 => 127
    1 => 5
  ]
]
```

And here's an example target sum:

```
$target = 32;
```

Here's the function I have so far:

```php
public function findNumberCombination($array, $targetSum)
{
    $foundPairs = [];
    $n = count($array);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
        for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $n; $j++) {
            $pairSum = $array[$i][1] + $array[$j][1];
            if ($pairSum == $targetSum) {
                $foundPairs[] = [$array[$i][0], $array[$j][0]];
            } else {
                for ($k = $j + 1; $k < $n; $k++) {
                    $pairSum = $array[$i][1] + $array[$j][1] + $array[$k][1];
                    if ($pairSum == $targetSum) {
                        $foundPairs[] = [$array[$i][0], $array[$j][0], $array[$k][0]];
                    } else {
                        // continue checking larger combinations
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $foundPairs;
}
```

The code works for the provided example, returning the correct pairs, but I'll need to modify it to handle larger arrays with more nested arrays. Is there a more efficient and scalable way to approach this problem?

Comment: Recursion. For each element in the array you search for a combination of remaining elements that adds up to `$sum - $cur`. It's further optimized by sorting the array and breaking out of the loop when the elements are too large to be viable anymore. I'd show an example, but I have no idea what the significance of the arrays you've given is. Is the `[0]` element just an id and `[1]` is the actual number?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be looking for *pairs* of numbers. Consider updating your problem description to be more accurate, to get better responses.

Comment: Index 0 is the product number and index 1 is the product inventory. For example, I have 3 products, each of which is not equal to my goal, and I want to see if their sum is equal to my goal or not. @Sammitch

Comment: @GregSchmidt
I have a goal, for example, 13 and I have three products, for example, $array = [0=>[0=>1,1=>11],2=>[0=>12,1=>9],2=> [0=>10,1=>2] ] I want to see how many numbers can be added together in this presentation that I have to reach my number 13 and the length of the string may be longer.

Comment: So in this case you'd want to get IDs 1 and 10, because their values are 11 and 2 which add up to 13?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of the recursion strategy I mentioned in my comment:

```php
function findsums($input, $sum, $start=0) {
    for( 
        $i = $start, $c = count($input);
        $i < $c;
        ++$i
    ) {
        $cur = $input[$i];
        $rem = $sum - $cur;
        
        // bounds    
        if( $rem == 0 ) {
            // this is the last element
            yield [$cur];
            return;
        } else if( $rem < 0 ) {
            // $cur too big
            return;
        } else if( array_sum(array_slice($input, $i+1)) < $sum ) {
            // all the remaining items in the input add up to less than the sum
            return;
        }
        
        foreach( findsums($input, $rem, $i+1) as $answer ) {
            yield array_merge([$cur], $answer);
        }
    }
}

$input = range(1,10);

foreach( findsums_new($input, 13) as $result ) {
    printf("%d: %s\n", array_sum($result), json_encode($result));
}
```

Output:

```
13: [1,2,3,7]
13: [1,2,4,6]
13: [1,2,10]
13: [1,3,4,5]
13: [1,3,9]
13: [1,4,8]
13: [1,5,7]
13: [2,3,8]
13: [2,4,7]
13: [2,5,6]
13: [3,4,6]
13: [3,10]
13: [4,9]
13: [5,8]
13: [6,7]
```

**edit:** I've swapped out the original implementation for one that is much kinder to the stack, and with slightly improved bounds checking.

For reference, the original code was as below, but also icluding the improved bounds checking.

```php
function findsums($input, $sum, $start=0) {
    $cur = $input[$start];
    $rem = $sum - $cur;

    // bounds    
    if( $rem == 0 ) {
        // this is the last element
        yield [$cur];
        return;
    } else if( $rem < 0 ) {
        // $cur too big
        return;
    } else if( array_sum(array_slice($input, $start+1)) < $sum ) {
        // all the remaining items in the input add up to less than the sum
        return;
    }
    
    // yield all [cur] + sub-array answers
    foreach( findsums($input, $rem, $start+1) as $answer) {
        yield array_merge([$cur], $answer);
    }

    // yield all sub-array answers
    yield from findsums($input, $sum, $start+1);
}
```

The trouble with this one is that it keeps a *lot* more open calls on the stack, which could become a problem for processing larger sets. Otherwise I believe all other performance metrics are roughly equivalent.